# POST request hangs (timeout) when trying to parse request body, running Koa on Firebase Cloud Functions

Tags: node.js, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-functions, koa

I'm working on a small website, serving static files using Firebase Hosting (FH) and rewriting all requests to a single function on Firebase Cloud Functions (FCF), where I'm using Koa (with koa-router) to handle the requests. However, when I try to parse the body of a POST request using koa-bodyparser, the service just hangs until it eventually times out.

The same thing occurs when using other body parsers, such as koa-body, and it seems to persist no matter where I put the parser, unless I put it after the router, in which case the problem goes away, though I still can't access the data, since it never gets a chance to be parsed(?).

The following is a stripped-down version of the code that's causing the problem:

```js
import * as functions from 'firebase-functions'
import * as Koa from 'koa'
import * as KoaRouter from 'koa-router'
import * as KoaBodyParser from 'koa-bodyparser'

const app = new Koa()
const router = new KoaRouter()

app.use(KoaBodyParser())

router.post('/', (context) => {
  // do some stuff with the data
})

app.use(router.routes())

export const serve = functions.https.onRequest(app.callback())
```

I'm still pretty new to all of these tools and I might be missing something completely obvious, but I can't seem to find the solution anywhere. If I'm not mistaken, FCF automatically parses requests, but Koa is unable to access that data unless it does the parsing itself, so I'd assume that something is going wrong between FCF's automatic parsing and the parser used by Koa.

I haven't been able to produce any actual errors or useful error messages, other than a Gateway Timeout (504), so I don't have much to go on and won't be able to provide you with much more than I already have.

How do I go about getting a hold of the data?

Answer (score 5):

Firebase already parses the body.
https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/http-events#read_values_from_the_request

It appears that the provided Koa body parsing middlewares don't know what to do with an "already parsed" body (ie an object vs an unparsed string), so the middleware ends up getting confused and does some sort of an infinite loop.

A solution is to use **ctx.req.body** because it's already parsed. :)

Koa rocks!

Comment: Thank you for this. I've been spending my whole day for this. This needs more attention.

Comment: It's bizarre that this results in an infinite loop.  This also isn't just relegated to Koa - I came upon this answer from NextJS, which has the exact same behavior but a very different solution.  See this answer if you're on NextJS: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63975702/2738164