# Why do I get a "502 Gateway" error from NextJs app hosted on Firebase for POST requests only?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, next.js, firebase-hosting

I started to build an API using NextJs framework. I want it to be hosted on Firebase *(Hosting and Functions)*. Everything is working as long as I send only GET requests. When I send a POST request I receive a *"502 Bad Gateway"* error.

It's very simple to reproduce. You just have to download and deploy the example provided by the team developing NextJs.

- create a new project on [Firebase](https://console.firebase.google.com/) console
- install the "[with Firebase hosting](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/tree/canary/examples/with-firebase-hosting)" example
- change the project name in the [.firebaserc (line 3)](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/blob/canary/examples/with-firebase-hosting/.firebaserc#L3) file
- create a folder *"api"* under the folder *"pages"*
- create a file *"hello.js"* under the folder *"api"* and add the following snippet

  ```js
  export default async (req, res) => {
    const {
      body,
      method
    } = req;

    console.log("method :>> ", method);
    console.log("body :>> ", body);

    switch (method) {
    case "POST":
      res.status(200).end(`Method ${method} supported!`);
      break;
    default:
      res.setHeader("Allow", ["POST"]);
      res.status(405).end(`Method ${method} Not Allowed`);
    }
  };
  ```
- deploy the app
- send a GET request to "https://[project-name].web.app/api/hello" and see it works
- send a POST request to "https://[project-name].web.app/api/hello" and see it does not work

Do you have a the same error as me?

I spent 2 days to read articles, watch videos and try different configurations. You can even update the [firebaseFunctions](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/blob/canary/examples/with-firebase-hosting/firebaseFunctions.js#L16) to add a `console.log` and see the POST request is caught by the Firebase Cloud Function but the NextJs server does not pass it to our API like it does for a GET request. It's out of my skills range...

Below the output you should have. The POST request should be answered with `200 - Method POST is supported!`.

[image]

Comment: I have another project using ExpressJs and I never encountered this issue.

Comment: I'm inclined to think it's caused by `res.status(204).end(``Method ${method} supported!``);` not anything else. Try with `res.status(204).end();` instead.

Comment: @samthecodingman If you try it you'll see there is no log on Firebase Cloud Functions. It means the method is not called. I updated the snippet (thank you for your help!)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This was a real pain to track down, but after poking around myself for a while, I found that the same issue crops up for PUT and PATCH requests. Which suggested that it had something to do with the body of the request. Annoyingly, after finding that out, I stumbled across the thread of [Issue #7960](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/7960), where they found the same problem.

Simply put, the body of the request processed once by `https.onRequest()` and then `nextjsHandle()` tries to parse it again. Because the body was handled already, the `raw-body` module (within `nextjsHandle()`) waits indefinitely for `'data'` events that will never come.

Currently, there isn't a way to turn off the body parsing done by `https.onRequest()`, so it must be disabled on the next.js end. Unfortunately, there isn't a global off switch for body parsing that can be added in `next.config.js` and it must be done for each and every API route (the files in `pages/api`) (which may change if the proposed fix in [PR #16169](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/pull/16169) is added).

To disable body parsing for a given route, you add the following to the route's file

```js
export const config = {
  api: {
    // disables call to body parsing module
    bodyParser: false,
  }
};
```

However, as mentioned in [Issue #7960](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/7960) by [@rscotten](https://github.com/rscotten), you might also want to use `next dev` while developing your app, so you need to enable it while using `next dev` but disable it while deployed. This can be done using

```js
export const config = {
  api: {
    // disables call to body parsing module while deployed
    bodyParser: process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production',
  }
};
```

Applying these changes to `hello.js` gives:

```js
export default async (req, res) => {
  const {
    body,
    method
  } = req;

  console.log("method :>> ", method);
  console.log("body :>> ", body);

  switch (method) {
  case "POST":
    res.status(200).end(`Method ${method} supported!`);
    break;
  default:
    res.setHeader("Allow", ["POST"]);
    res.status(405).end(`Method ${method} Not Allowed`);
  }
};

export const config = {
  api: {
    // disable nextjs's body parser while deployed
    // (as body parsing is handled by `https.onRequest()`),
    // but enable it for local development using `next dev`
    bodyParser: process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production',
  }
};
```

Comment: I was looking on the wrong way. I already had same issue with an ExpressJs app but the error I received was clear, I could solved it quickly. I was starting to replace NextJs by ExpressJs when I saw your reply. Thank you very much Sam for your help!

Comment: There must also have Firebase Hosting configuration issue. Because now I'm have "502 Bad Gateway" while using Puppeteer on Firebase Cloud Functions. The "goto" method does not finish. Locally everything works fine and in an other project I can use Puppeteer without any trouble. The difference is I do not redirect all requests to the Next/Express server but only those under "/api/**". I'm investigating on it...

Comment: I was wrong but instead of delete my comment let's keep history of what happened after the gateway issue of the Express/Next server. I am using Puppeteer in the API I expose through the server. I still was receiving `502 - Bad Gateway` error because after Puppeteer loaded the page it was waiting too long. I simply remove "an extra" `waitForNavigation` call. Locally no problem with it but on Firebase it was preventing my script to continue.